# How is this incorrect?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-choice

I was talking to my Italian Professora and we were joking about my attempts to flirt with a person. However, when I told her about the line `Tu non sei il sole ma fate la mia mattina` (You are not the sun, but you make up my morning); she said my Italian grammar was incorrect. Before she could offer an explanation, she had to charge off to a meeting. My Italian friend does not know why its wrong, and I can't tell either. Should `fate` be `tu fai`? Is that my issue?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Thanks, @Charo! As a current student learning Italian, I feel this website will be perfect for me in the long run.

Comment: It's a lousy line, by the way.

Comment: @magma Each to their own opinion!

Comment: @DigitalVeer ahah right! just willing to help. but if it works for you, that's fine.

Comment: @magma I mean, I am accepting suggestions if you have one :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I was talking to my Italian *Professora*...

First of all I should warn you that the most used feminine form of "professore" is [professor-*essa*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/professore/); "professor-*a*" is not incorrect, but less usual.

As for your sentence,

> *Tu* non *sei* il sole ma *fate* la mia mattina,

from a grammatical point of view the problem is what you've understood: you begin the sentence using *tu... sei* (singular), but conclude it using *(voi) fate* (plural), as if you're referring not to the same person but to several people or also to the same person but [with a less informal tone](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1495/2056). Unfortunately both pronouns (tu, voi) are translated by the English word "you".

Moreover, I think you're attempting a literal translation of [an idiomatic sentence](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/make+your+day.html) (or are you referring to [Elvis' song](https://youtu.be/b3Qf6hLxT4M)?) by saying «fate(/fai) la mia mattina»: if you're referring to the action of the Sun and to the fact that the person you're talking to warms your heart and makes you happy, note that we usually say:

> illumini il mio giorno

or

> illumini il mio cielo.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! I also like the phrase "illumini il mio giorno" over "fai mia mattina". Definitely will accept

Comment: @DigitalVeer You're very welcome! And thanks to you too! :)

Comment: Potresti prenderti un attimo per leggere questa [domanda sul Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1359)? Grazie mille!