# C'è ‘voseo’ in italiano?

Tags: word-usage, regional, pronouns, formal, colloquial

Noi ispanoparlanti abbiamo il [*voseo*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo): è un fenomeno che consiste nel sostituire il pronome *tú* con *vos*. Per chi sa un po' di spagnolo, le coniugazioni dei verbi sono un po' diverse da quelle che usiamo con *vosotros*; il suo uso è percepito come informale — azzarderei a dire che è persino più informale
del *tuteo* (l'uso in spagnolo delle forme verbali e pronominali della seconda persona singolare in situazioni informali che è più conosciuto).

Tuttavia, fate attenzione a [questo dialogo](https://youtu.be/9OEAdVI4i-k) (dal minuto 0:22):

> [...]
> — Come sta? 
> — Eh? 
> — Dico **Lei**, come sta? 
> — Lei? 
> — Lei, come si sente Lei? 
> — Ma cu chi' parl' chist'? 
> — No, sta parlann' cu' tè, mamma. È che mia mamma è abituata al **voi**. Da queste parti non si usa il Lei. 
> [...]

È vero che c'è ‘voseo’ anche in italiano? C'è soltanto a Napoli (dove si svolge il film) o è più esteso? Sostituisce il *Lei* (cioè, è formale) o invece il *tu* (cioè, è informale)? Rispondete onestamente, per favore ☺: se lo voglio usare, penseranno male di me?

Comment: Autorizzo qualsiasi ‘limazzione’, non è necessario chiedere permesso

Comment: Se ho capito bene la tua domanda, mi sembra che se ne sia già parlato qui. In particolare: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/difference-between-darsi-del-tu-and-del-lei/1364#1364 e https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1495/who-decided-the-switch-from-voi-to-lei-in-the-20th-century Rispondono alla tua domanda?

Comment: @DaG: Veramente se ne parla in quei post, ma l'uso in spagnolo americano è diverso da quello italiano: è usato per sostituire il pronome "tú", quindi si usa in situazioni informali, e le  coniugazioni dei verbi sono un po' diverse di quelle che si usano per il pronome "vosotros" perché hanno subito evoluzioni morfologiche.

Comment: Ciao, @tac. In italiano sono "limature", ma non sono per niente sicura che questo termine si usi per riferirsi a un testo (non sono italiana, ma non ho mai incontrato questo uso di "limatura"). Forse sarebbe meglio usare "revisioni" o "correzioni".

Comment: Grazie, @Charo: temevo in effetti che mi fosse sfuggito qualcosa. Temo quindi che la risposta sia un semplice “no”.

Comment: @Tutti capisco, "voi" è formale ma è molto raro. Potete marcare la domanda come duplicato. Grazie

Comment: Io sono di Napoli, 'voi' lì è formale, ma non è affatto raro, perché è termine popolare e dialettale, è comunissimo, normale. Se ad esempio si va a un bar, il barista facilmente può chiederti "Lo volete il caffé"?, è comunissimo. I napoletani quando parlano italiano non lo usano mai, ma anche io alle volte se voglio in un certo contesto passare a un tono più popolare o dialettale, lo uso, ad esempio se parlo con una persona che lo usa. Ma comunque per un non napoletano è meglio usare sempre il Lei, se no si fa confusione.

Comment: In Italiano standard, non regionale, no, è praticamente scomparso.

Comment: Nell'italiano contemporaneo, ci sono due usi di "voi": quello burocratico (esempio di G. Berruto: "Vogliate prendere atto dell'imposibilità della venuta dei sottoscritti") e quello dialettale-regionale menzionato da @BakerStreet.

Comment: @Charo Riguardo alla 'limatura' , cerca nel Wikzionario: "3. Perfezionare un testo..."

Comment: @tac: Perché non poni una domanda su questo uso di "limatura"? Non sono sicura su fino a che punto Wikizionario sia da considerarsi affidabile.

Comment: Io penso che abbia ragione Wikzionario, *limatura* riferita a un testo o in genere in senso figurato si usa.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @BakerStreet!

Comment: Figurati. Non è che si usi così comunemente, ma è un termine normale. Vedi ad esempio https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/L/limatura.shtml

Comment: Ad esempio, nella frase scritta da @tac, se non avesse messo le virgolette intorno a *limatura*, sarebbe stato meglio specificare limatura *del testo*, forse solo *limatura* sarebbe suonato strano, poco chiaro. Ma insomma, sono sfumature.

Comment: Forse la formula che si sta cercando è “vossìa”? Si tratta di una formula abbreviata di “vossignore” (voi, Signore) o “vossignorìa” (voi, Signorìa), entrambe formule di grande rispetto in uso prevalentemente nel Sud d’Italia

Comment: @FabrizioDavia No, chiedevo riguardo a l'uso di voi—sarei stato più adeguato chiamare ‘*voiseo*’? In ogni caso grazie, è buono sapere anche non abbia domandatto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scusatemi ma non posso postare commenti, solo risposte. A me sembra che l'OP, avendo trovato menzionata in un film la differenza tra "voi" e "Lei" si chiedesse se in italiano il "voi" fosse più informale del "tu", come succede in certi paesi ispanoablanti. La risposta è no: il romanzo è ambientato a Napoli, e a Napoli si usa il "voi" a posto del "Lei" come forma di cortesia. In italiano contemporaneo il "voi" non si usa più come forma di cortesia. La differenza quindi è solo regionale. Il "voi" era usato in passato in italiano standard come forma intermedia fra il "tu" e il "Lei", questo era quello che ho cercato di spiegare!

Comment: «se in italiano il "voi" fosse meno informale del "tu", come succede in certi paesi ispanoablanti»: Intendi _più_ informale, vero?

Answer (score 0):

Ciao tac! In passato (almeno fino alla fine dell'Ottocento, cioè del 1800) c'erano tre maniere per rivolgersi a una persona in italiano: "tu", la più informale, quando c'era una grande confidenza; "voi", quando c'era una certa confidenza e "Lei", la più formale, quando non c'era nessuna confidenza. Capita spesso, leggendo le vecchie corrispondenze, di trovare qualcuno che chiede al suo corrispondente di dargli del "voi" e non più del "Lei", adesso che si conoscono un po' meglio. Gli usi regionali cambiavano moltissimo: in alcune regioni si usava solo o soprattutto il "voi", in altre il "Lei". Come si sa, verso la fine del regime fascista (1938) venne abolito l'uso del "Lei", considerato spagnoleggiante ("Usted") e effeminato: ufficialmente si poteva usare solo il "voi". Dopo la seconda guerra mondiale si preferì l'uso del "Lei" perché "voi" ricordava troppo il periodo fascista. Adesso "Lei" è l'unica forma di cortesia che esista in italiano standard, "voi" è usato solo in alcune regioni o nei film e nei romanzi ambientati nelle epoche passate.

Comment: Però, se ho ben capito la domanda e il commento di Charo alla domanda, il nostro “voi” non corrisponde al “voseo”, che è più informale e dal punto di vista grammaticale è diverso dal “vosotros” (che è la normale 2a persona plurale), mentre in italiano il “voi” di cortesia e la 2a persona plurale funzionano allo stesso modo.

Comment: In italiano "tu" è il modo più informale di rivolgersi a una persona; "voi" e "Lei" esistono ma sono entrambi più formali del "tu".

Comment: @DaG ha ragione. Forse dovrei scrivere una risposta. Cercherò di farlo quando abbia un po' di tempo.

Comment: Dici a me, @Sbaracchino? Lo so bene, sono italiano. Quello che stavo spiegando è che il *vos* di cui parla l'OP sembra non corrispondere al *voi* italiano.